# Let $(X,Y)$ be a 2D stochastic variable with density function $f(x,y) = 3/2 xy1_A(x,y)$. Find the distribution of $(X + Y)$ and $(X - Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

> Let $(X,Y)$, a 2D stochastic variable with density function $f(x,y) = 3/2 xy1_A(x,y)$, where $A$ is the set of all positive values bound by the line $y = 2-x$.

Find the distribution of $(X + Y)$ and $(X - Y)$.

Things I know and thoughts about a solution.

1. I know that the variables are not independent as their J.D.F doesn't equal the product of the marginals distributions. I also know that a distribution function is equal to the integral of the density function but I'm not sure how this applies here. Am I supposed to sum the marginal distribution functions and integrate that to find the distribution?
2. I also know there is the possibility of transforming the distribution but again I'm not sure how to apply this. Do I take the reciprocal of the integral of the density function, if so with respect to which variable? There is also a consideration of limits too I suppose.

Comment: I would first of all calculate the pdf´s. For instance, the pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\int_0^{2-x} \frac32 xy \,dy$

Comment: Ok so this will give me the distribution for X. I do the same for Y then add them? Is it that simple? Then the same for X - Y I suppose?

Comment: Yes, but it is not simple.

Comment: You can apply the convolution formula, such that the integrand is no longer the product of marginal pdf (as they are not independent), but the joint pdf instead.

Comment: Why is it not simple? Two separate integrals and sum the results. You're being very vague in your answer. Am i missing something? We've not been introduced to the convolution formula but I'll take a look. Thank you